# Why is Chrome on MacOS inconsistently not recognizing 3 finger swipes?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, trackpad, multi-touch

I have used three finger forward/back swipe on MacOS for almost a decade in Chrome for forward/backwards on pages. This has consistently worked well and been flawless.

Within the past month or so, this has inconsistently been not working. I know the trackpad is working because my debugging has been:

- Try to 3-finger forward/backwards in Chrome, it fails
- Go to other app, use 3-finger forward/back, see it works (100% of time)
- Go back to Chrome, it still fails

The part I am really confused by is that it *sometimes* works in Chrome still.

I can also consistently quit/restart Chrome to "reenable" this when it stops working.

Are there troubleshooting techniques to understand what might have changed to cause this? Or an obvious solution to fix this?

OS: 11.2.3 (20D91)
Chrome: latest version(s)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i believe its something to do with the ublock origin extension. try turning the extension on and off and the function should work again. same issue was happening to me and unfortunately need to do this manually as a work around until they fix it. :(

Comment: This seems to be the issue for me too!

Comment: let me know if you find a way to fix it

Comment: @enderland did u find a solution to this issue?

Comment: No. I just turn off/on ublock when i notice it :\